# Use R and Latex to Automate Powerpoint Reports

Tags: r, latex, powerpoint, sweave

I have a report template that I use quite often.  The analysis is completed in R, but at the moment here is my workflow:

1. Use R to run the analysis and export the results to csv files
2. Use excel macros to read in the data, manipulate chart/create tables
3. Again using excel, "automate" the charts/tables to Powerpoint

The more I am exposed to Latex, R, and Reproducible Research, I feel like there should be a way to stay within R and send my results to Powerpoint.  I know there is the R2PPT package, but I am trying to think of all options.  I don't think sending pictures of my graphs will be an issue, it's more the table creation that has me stumped.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated!  Unforunately, yes, I need to continue to use PPT.

Comment: If PowerPoint can import pdf's, you could make all your tables with Sweave and import the resulting pdfs into PowerPoint.

Comment: PowerPoint can't import PDFs.

Comment: Thats a great idea.  Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: try www.pptxbuilder.com

Comment: Just made a new package, export, that allows one to do exactly that - see my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you automate PowerPoint from R?  Ie, start it, get access to the object model, etc?

If so, you should be able to create the tables directly within PPT.

Comment: The R2PPT package provides a great first step, but the thought would be that it may actually be easier to automate a Latex-like table, but I am unsure as to how to get that table into PPT.

Comment: Just had a quick look at the R2PPT PDF doc.  It doesn't look like it doesn't give you the kind of object model access you'd need to build the tables directly in PPT.  It does give you a way to add slides and to add pictures to a slide, so if you can get your table into a picture in a format that PPT can import, you might have it whipped.  EMF, WMF, BMP, PNG, JPG and a few others would do.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to build latex tables and save them as one of the image files above?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid.  I do a lot w/ PPT (manually, programmatically) but don't know Latex.

Comment: Steve, can you provide examples of how you programmatically interact with PPT?

Comment: I maintain a largish PPT FAQ site with quite a few programming examples/tips.  Have a look at www.pptfaq.com and scroll down to the programming section for code examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution conditional on you being able to display PDF's where you would normally use powerpoint.

You will need:

1) LateX
2) R
3) Beamer latex package.

Of these the only one you may have to search for is Beamer. You can then open up a new latex document, give it document type beamer, and then write latex and R just like you would for an article. Send the code to R, get results back, typeset the results and you're done. I haven't been back to Powerpoint since I learned about Beamer.

I see that you need to remain within Powerpoint, so this advice is probably not useful. That being said, Beamer outputs to PDF, and I've given many presentations where everyone else used powerpoint and have never had a problem

Comment: I think this is the ideal solution.  Once you put data in PowerPoint you don't want it edited.  Who cooks books, right?  LaTeX - Beamer gets you great control, and read-only content.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sweave and odfSweave.  You can produce R reports as pdfs using sweave and then copy/paste into powerpoint, or use odfweave to produce your report as an LibreOffice odt file, then open that and copy/paste into powerpoint from LibreOffice.

Comment: Although it is listed as experimental, you could try to use odfWeave to write to an odp file, and just use Impress or maybe PowerPoint to convert the file to a ppt.

Comment: Thx for the response.  Ideally everything with be automated programattically; zero manual intervention.  Ive been exposed to sweave and I think it is fantastic, but the output must be a PPT deck.  R2PPT is a package that facilitates this to a point, I am stumped on how to produce a latex-like table within PPT.  An image would be fine if possible.

Comment: There are a few packages that offer a graphical output for tables. See `grid.table()` in the package `gridExtra` for [some examples](http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `R2PPT` is the best solution. Another option I start exploring is creating a Visual Basic Script (.vbs) which opens Powerpoint, inserts slides and inserts EMFs generated by R.

Answer (score 0):

The `ReporteRs` package is designed to do exactly this workflow.  If your output could be a pdf or html, definitely consider `knitr` or `slidify`, which do not support `.pptx`.  But here's an example using `ReporteRs`:

```
library('ReporteRs')

# set default font size to 24
options( "ReporteRs-fontsize" = 24 )

doc = pptx( )

# add a slide with layout "Title Slide"
doc = addSlide( doc, slide.layout = "Title Slide" )
#set the main title
doc = addTitle( doc, "Presentation About Cars" ) 

# add a slide with layout "Title and Content" then add content
doc = addSlide( doc, slide.layout = "Title and Content" )
doc = addTitle( doc, "Cars dataset", level = 1 )
data(mtcars)

library('ggplot2')
car_plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, col=cyl)) + 
              geom_point() + geom_smooth() + 
              xlab('Horsepower (Hp)') + ylab('Miles per Gallon (MpG')


doc = addPlot( doc = doc, fun=print, x = car_plot )

doc = addSlide( doc, slide.layout = "Title and Content" )
doc = addTitle( doc, "More about cars dataset", level = 1 )
doc = addParagraph(doc, paste("The correlation between Hp and MpG is",
                              round(with(mtcars, cor(hp, mpg)),3))
                   )

writeDoc( doc, file = "presentation_about_cars.pptx" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my new export package that just came out an CRAN and that allows one to both export graphs and statistical tables from R to Powerpoint and Word.
See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and
https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export.

For example:

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)

## export of ggplot2 plot
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))
# export to Powerpoint      
graph2ppt(file="ggplot2_plot.pptx", width=7, height=6) 
# export to Word
graph2doc(file="ggplot2_plot.docx", width=7, height=6)

## export of aov Anova output as table
fit=aov(yield ~ block + N * P + K, npk)
x=summary(fit)
# export to Powerpoint
table2ppt(x=x,file="table_aov.pptx")
table2ppt(x=x,file="table_aov.pptx",digits=4,append=TRUE)
table2ppt(x=x,file="table_aov.pptx",digits=4,digitspvals=1,
          font="Times New Roman",pointsize=16,append=TRUE)
# export to Word
table2doc(x=x)
# export to Excel
table2excel(x=x, file = "table_aov.xlsx",digits=4,digitspvals=1,
            sheetName = "Anova_table", add.rownames = TRUE)
# export to Latex
table2tex(x=x)
```